# How to use Unity Official WebRTC package for view sharing and how to define a id for RTCServer in Unity WebRTC project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webrtc

Sorry for I was a freshman and might have a simple problem for you. I hope to use Unity's official WebRTC package([enter link description here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.webrtc)) to make a camera's view sharing, which means letting different devices which belong to the same WLAN network can see the same view shared from a Unity program's camera (also belong to the same WLAN network). My problem is, I don't know how to let the example code run on different devices and can share the same view.

Here is the sample scene:
[Start Scence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi7e0.png)

After I press the Start Button:
[After Press "Start"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7LK2.png)

After I press the "Call" Button:
[After Press "Call"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Muw.png)

This sample scene (the scene name in this example project is "MultiplePeerConnections") means you can share a camera's view to the other two devices. And here is the example code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace Unity.WebRTC.Samples
{
    class MultiplePeerConnectionsSample : MonoBehaviour
    {
#pragma warning disable 0649
        [SerializeField] private Button startButton;
        [SerializeField] private Button callButton;
        [SerializeField] private Button hangUpButton;
        [SerializeField] private Vector2Int streamingSize;
        [SerializeField] private Camera cam;
        [SerializeField] private RawImage sourceImage;
        [SerializeField] private RawImage receiveImage1;
        [SerializeField] private RawImage receiveImage2;
        [SerializeField] private AudioSource sourceAudio;
        [SerializeField] private AudioSource receiveAudio1;
        [SerializeField] private AudioSource receiveAudio2;
        [SerializeField] private Transform rotateObject;
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip audioclipStereoSample;
#pragma warning restore 0649

        private static RTCConfiguration configuration = new RTCConfiguration
        {
            iceServers = new[] {new RTCIceServer {urls = new[] {"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}}}
        };

        private RTCPeerConnection pc1Local, pc1Remote, pc2Local, pc2Remote;
        private MediaStream sourceStream;

        private void Awake()
        {
            WebRTC.Initialize(WebRTCSettings.EncoderType, WebRTCSettings.LimitTextureSize);
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            WebRTC.Dispose();
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            StartCoroutine(WebRTC.Update());

            startButton.onClick.AddListener(Setup);
            callButton.onClick.AddListener(Call);
            hangUpButton.onClick.AddListener(HangUp);

            startButton.interactable = true;
            callButton.interactable = false;
            hangUpButton.interactable = false;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (rotateObject != null)
            {
                rotateObject.Rotate(1, 2, 3);
            }
        }

        private void Setup()
        {
            Debug.Log("Set up source/receive streams");
            sourceStream = new MediaStream();

            var videoTrack = cam.CaptureStreamTrack(streamingSize.x, streamingSize.y, 0);
            sourceStream.AddTrack(videoTrack);
            sourceImage.texture = cam.targetTexture;

            sourceAudio.clip = audioclipStereoSample;
            sourceAudio.loop = true;
            sourceAudio.Play();
            var audioTrack = new AudioStreamTrack(sourceAudio);
            sourceStream.AddTrack(audioTrack);

            startButton.interactable = false;
            callButton.interactable = true;
        }

        private void Call()
        {
            Debug.Log("Starting calls");

            pc1Local = new RTCPeerConnection(ref configuration);
            pc1Remote = new RTCPeerConnection(ref configuration);
            pc1Remote.OnTrack = e =>
            {
                if (e.Track is VideoStreamTrack videoTrack && !videoTrack.IsDecoderInitialized)
                {
                    receiveImage1.texture = videoTrack.InitializeReceiver(streamingSize.x, streamingSize.y);
                }

                if (e.Track is AudioStreamTrack audioTrack)
                {
                    audioTrack.OnAudioReceived += clip =>
                    {
                        receiveAudio1.clip = clip;
                        receiveAudio1.loop = true;
                        receiveAudio1.Play();
                    };
                }
            };
            pc1Local.OnIceCandidate = candidate => pc1Remote.AddIceCandidate(candidate);
            pc1Remote.OnIceCandidate = candidate => pc1Local.AddIceCandidate(candidate);
            Debug.Log("pc1: created local and remote peer connection object");

            pc2Local = new RTCPeerConnection(ref configuration);
            pc2Remote = new RTCPeerConnection(ref configuration);
            pc2Remote.OnTrack = e =>
            {
                if (e.Track is VideoStreamTrack videoTrack && !videoTrack.IsDecoderInitialized)
                {
                    receiveImage2.texture = videoTrack.InitializeReceiver(streamingSize.x, streamingSize.y);
                }

                if (e.Track is AudioStreamTrack audioTrack)
                {
                    audioTrack.OnAudioReceived += clip =>
                    {
                        receiveAudio2.clip = clip;
                        receiveAudio2.loop = true;
                        receiveAudio2.Play();
                    };
                }
            };
            pc2Local.OnIceCandidate = candidate => pc2Remote.AddIceCandidate(candidate);
            pc2Remote.OnIceCandidate = candidate => pc2Local.AddIceCandidate(candidate);
            Debug.Log("pc2: created local and remote peer connection object");

            foreach (var track in sourceStream.GetTracks())
            {
                pc1Local.AddTrack(track, sourceStream);
                pc2Local.AddTrack(track, sourceStream);
            }

            Debug.Log("Adding local stream to pc1Local/pc2Local");

            StartCoroutine(NegotiationPeer(pc1Local, pc1Remote));
            StartCoroutine(NegotiationPeer(pc2Local, pc2Remote));

            callButton.interactable = false;
            hangUpButton.interactable = true;
        }

        private void HangUp()
        {
            foreach (var track in sourceStream.GetTracks())
            {
                track.Dispose();
            }
            sourceStream.Dispose();
            sourceStream = null;
            pc1Local.Close();
            pc1Remote.Close();
            pc2Local.Close();
            pc2Remote.Close();
            pc1Local.Dispose();
            pc1Remote.Dispose();
            pc2Local.Dispose();
            pc2Remote.Dispose();
            pc1Local = null;
            pc1Remote = null;
            pc2Local = null;
            pc2Remote = null;

            sourceImage.texture = null;
            sourceAudio.Stop();
            sourceAudio.clip = null;
            receiveImage1.texture = null;
            receiveAudio1.Stop();
            receiveAudio1.clip = null;
            receiveImage2.texture = null;
            receiveAudio2.Stop();
            receiveAudio2.clip = null;

            startButton.interactable = true;
            callButton.interactable = false;
            hangUpButton.interactable = false;
        }

        private static void OnCreateSessionDescriptionError(RTCError error)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed to create session description: {error.message}");
        }

        private static IEnumerator NegotiationPeer(RTCPeerConnection localPeer, RTCPeerConnection remotePeer)
        {
            var opCreateOffer = localPeer.CreateOffer();
            yield return opCreateOffer;

            if (opCreateOffer.IsError)
            {
                OnCreateSessionDescriptionError(opCreateOffer.Error);
                yield break;
            }

            var offerDesc = opCreateOffer.Desc;
            yield return localPeer.SetLocalDescription(ref offerDesc);
            Debug.Log($"Offer from LocalPeer \n {offerDesc.sdp}");
            yield return remotePeer.SetRemoteDescription(ref offerDesc);

            var opCreateAnswer = remotePeer.CreateAnswer();
            yield return opCreateAnswer;

            if (opCreateAnswer.IsError)
            {
                OnCreateSessionDescriptionError(opCreateAnswer.Error);
                yield break;
            }

            var answerDesc = opCreateAnswer.Desc;
            yield return remotePeer.SetLocalDescription(ref answerDesc);
            Debug.Log($"Answer from RemotePeer \n {answerDesc.sdp}");
            yield return localPeer.SetRemoteDescription(ref answerDesc);
        }
    }
}
```

When I unpack this project into two scenes and output two .exe files with the same name, one for show and one for the call, it cannot work, even cannot connect with each other.

I think the problem is maybe I didn't sign an ID string or something when using RTCIceServer, which is shown below.

```
private static RTCConfiguration configuration = new RTCConfiguration
        {
            iceServers = new[] {new RTCIceServer {urls = new[] {"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}}}
        };
```

But I don't know how to get over it. Really thanks for any help.